# Pair RDD with Array Values

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark. Trying to flatten the RDD from the below format.

```
rdd=((key),((value1,value2),Some((value3,value4))))
```

to

```
(key,value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

tried to map the values as below. with case class

```
case class outdata(Key: String, Value1: String, Value2: String, Value3:String, Value4:String)

rdd.map{case(x,y)=>outdata(x_.1,y._1._1,y._1._2,y._2._1,y._2._2)}
```

getting error `y._2._1 is not member`

Comment: `y._2` is type of `Option` which has two values `Some` or `None` so you have to extract the value using `get` or `getOrElse` or also `map`

Comment: Able to read the data using getOrElse, but unable to map the result data. getting an error **map is not a member of java.io.Serializable**. I have tried the below code.

rdd.map{case(x,y)=>y._2.getOrElse("NO").map(x=>(x._1,x._2))}

Answer (score 1):

Scala's pattern matching is expressive enough to do this without a case class:

`rdd.map{case (key : String, ((value1 : String, value2: String), Some((value3 : String, value4 : String)))) => (key, value1, value2, value3, value4) }`

Comment: I tried to map as above, but got the following error. 

found: String 
expected: (String)